# Website scanner for specific HTML tags?

Tags: html, css, web, tags

Basically I am part of a webteam with a website built in the CMS, EasySite (has over 3000 pages). I was wondering if there was a tool or any other way of scanning the HTML in each page for a specific tag (i.e. `style="font-size:10px"`).

Alot of people are copy and pasting content from MS Word which obviously copies the formatting too. Although it doesn't show on the desktop site, it shows up on mobile/tablet devices. So need this sorting on all current pages.

Comment: Does it have a database behind it that stores the pages? Could you query against it?

Comment: Using a CMS, you content is most probably in a database, so finding this should be a problem. Fixing it (= stripping those tags) can get quite more complicated though because of the ending tags. If not in a database, a text search on files should do the trick, with the same issue when time comes to fix it.

Comment: I am in a similar situation with about 2500 pages. We use a service called siteimprove its a paid service but works pretty well for web governance. I know there are similar products out there.

Comment: Doug, yeah we also use SiteImprove and have gone to them however it's a service they won't provide unfortunately.

Because the website was built in the CMS we don't have access to the raw HTML pages.

Comment: Bart, a simple text search would be fine, but we have over 3000 pages, and hell am I going through 300 pages.. :p

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. Mirror your site on your local filesystem (for example with `wget --mirror http://example.com`, see [manpage of wget](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget))
2. Work on the downloaded files to perform your search with the tools you like most (Python or [grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) – for example `grep -rn 'style="font-size:10px"' mirror_directory`)